# Allow WildFly management console to be accessible from only one computer

Tags: java, security, ubuntu-16.04, wildfly-10

I want the WildFly console to be accessible from only my PC. The WildFly is running on an Ubuntu based server on rack space. I want to access it with my windows running machine.
I tried the following interface with both my public and private IPs:

```
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.0.100}"/>
```

but it only allows me to access when I use the following in the management and public interface, which obviously can be a security breach:

```
<any-address/>
```

So, how can I allow only one IP?

Comment: Can you not just use <inet-address value="192.168.0.100"/>?

Comment: and this IP should be my public IP?

Comment: yes, as that's the IP the server will see

Comment: Ok Thanks, let me check if it works :)

Comment: Is `192.168.0.100` the address the local IP for the server or your Windows machine?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins It's the IP of my Windows Machine, but it can not be my local IP, it should be public.

Comment: That's not going to work then. The address is the address for the server to bind to not accept requests from. If you want to filter requests from a specific IP you'll likely have to do at the OS level.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, Thanks for the help, I allowed `<any-address/>` and restrict the IPs from IP tables :)